# Best practice to run a self finishing activity after every 30 minutes?

Tags: android, timer, repeat

I am using 2 activities, MainActivity and VideoAdActivity. VideoAdActivity closes as it finished playing video. How i can call start VideoAdActivity after every 30 minutes from MainActivity. Which is the best approach : TimerTask , Runnable , AlarmManager or somthing else ?
No requirements of background service.

Comment: TimerTask is  better.

Comment: TimerTask is better than other three you mentioned.

Comment: Runnable would be better as far as I know

Comment: right now it's starting from 0th min, 30th min, 60th min and so on,, i want  it like, 30th min, 60th min,,,

Answer (score 0):

According to me you have to use TimerTask. Because:

The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm receiver's onReceive() method is executing. This guarantees that the phone will not sleep until you have finished handling the broadcast. User have to finish handling, otherwise it will not sleep.

In Timer Task:
The TimerTask class represents a task to run at a specified time. The task may be run once or repeatedly. This is best to use if you want to just perform a task repeatdly. 
You can take help from : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html